# Struct value doesn't change with for loop range

Tags: for-loop, go, struct

I have a for-loop that iterates over my slice of `User`. But:

-When i use for with `range` this is my result

```
for _, u := range users {
    val := calcMem(u.sessionid)
    // total += val
    u.setMem(val)
}

Result:
[{user1 dp-tcp#64 2 0} {user2 dp-tcp#62 0} {user3 dp-tcp#83 4 0}]
```

-When i use a simple for loop:

```
for i := 0; i < len(users); i++ {
    val := calcMem(users[i].sessionid)
    // total += val
    users[i].setMem(val)
}

Result:
[{user1 dp-tcp#64 2 5287.092000000001} {user2 dp-tcp#62 3589.383999999999} {user3 dp-tcp#83 4 3956.012}]
```

Where i doing something wrong ?

---

-`setMem` function:

```
func (u *user) setMem(value float64) {
    u.memusage = value
}
```

Comment: Like all assignments, the value variable in a `range` is a copy of the value from the slice.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/YwoeFoFr1rk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you iteratw with way

```
for _, u := range users {
}
```

you get a copy of the slice value. So if you change it you change this copy.

If you wish you may take value by index and modify it:

```
for i := range users {
    users[i] = ....
}
```